# What is the proper configuration for an adjustable voltage divider circuit

Tags: voltage-divider

I am making a circuit that need a voltage reference that is adjustable. The the answer that many of us would think of is a voltage divider.

There are 2 configurations that I thought this can be done, and it is only now that I have wondered which is the proper or probably the best.

[image]

The configuration on the right seems to be the most optimal since it requires less parts.

Are the two configuration essentially the same? If not what are the pros and cons of the each configuration?

Comment: Well, for one thing, the one on the left can't go all the way to zero, As for which one is best, that would depend on how you define "best".

Comment: The best one is the one that meets your “specs” or measurable expectations.  Min, max [%] keep in mind Pots have a dynamic range of 200:1 or 0.5%. so you may want to decide on sensitivity and range .there are also options for 5 and 10 turn trimpots or using fixed R’s on either side of Pot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right one is the best for a number of reasons, the left version is very rarely used:

1: The right one can be adjusted linearly from 0-100%  (assuming a linear law potentiometer). Or it use a logarithmic law potentiometer that is preferred for audio applications.

2: The left one depends upon the actual resistance of the variable resistor that is usually not very well controlled (maybe 10-20%). The right one does not depend upon the absolute value.

3: The left one cannot be adjusted to give zero output. The minimum is when RV2 is at its maximum value, but the output will not be zero.

4: The left one puts a significant current through the wiper of the variable resistor. Because of contact resistance variations as it is adjusted this can cause noise in the output. It is not at all suitable for audio value control.

Comment: Thank you, the number 2: _does not depend upon the absolute value_ that just blew my mind, config 2 does just not care about tolerances.

Comment: @Jakequin It *does* care about linearity tolerance.

Comment: @Jakequin - agreed. Also if there is any signifcant load on the output it will be affected by the absolute resistance and not give a linear increase with rotation. The 0% and 100% outputs will not be affected by tolerance though.